# # character in request string

Tags: php

When a PHP site is requested like e.g. `somesite.php?a=some text # some more`

Currently it seems like `$_REQUEST["a"]` returns the string "some text ", how can I get "some text # some more". Are there other characters which get similar treatment by PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "#" character is special in the URL specification; it refers to a location on the page (named by an 'a' tag like: `<a name='top'>this is the top of the page</a>`). It, and everything after it, is not passed to the server (php).

Answer (score 8):

The hash (`#`) is a "[Fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)" (also informally known as an "anchor") and refers to a location *within* the page - and you're right, it doesn't get sent to the server.

It's the only URL character that behaves like this.

If you need to include a hash character in a URL, you need to encode it as `%23`

Answer (score 4):

```
somesite.php?a=<?=urlencode( "some text # some more" )?>
```

Turns it into:

```
somesite.php?a=some+text+%23+some+more
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The browser doesn't send the part of the url after the # to the server.

So, it's not PHP that removes that part of the URL, it never sees it.

Comment: Damn, that I didn't think of that :-)
Blaming our lovely PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can use urlencode() & urldecode() functions 
it will be %23 instead of # symbol

Answer (score 1):

If you have to have it, you can write javascript to re-post it for you:

```
<script>

function checkHash(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if(hash){
    // see if we've already included this
    var loc = window.location.pathname;
    if(!loc.indexOf('hashData=') >= 0){
      // hashData param not included
      window.location.href = loc + '&hashData=' + encodeURIComponent(hash) + hash;
    }
  }
};
checkHash();
</script>
```

There are some obvious issues with this (like it double-submits items).  Note - if someone clicks on a hash link in the page, the code won't re-run, so you would need to monitor the hash for changes.  You may or may not care about that case.

Comment: This solution comes in handy when you are using an ajax request to populate some sort of information anyway.

Comment: In general, I would say "don't put stuff in the hash that the server needs".

Answer (score 0):

The # character, and any characters that follow it, specify and anchor.
This is a point within the page that the browser will scroll to.

As far as I know, this is for the browser's use only, and is never transmitted to the server side - presumably because it means nothing to the server,